# I want to change header content using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the 'header content' as i click on the header. but my code doesn't  works.

This is my html div ..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

my JQuery is ..

```
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);

    $content = $header.next();

    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {

        $header.text(function () {

            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

});
```

Please help me

Comment: Checkout http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: do you want to change the content of <div class="header"><span>Expand</span> ?

Comment: your code is working fine. are you getting any error.

Comment: have you use jquery.min.js on your page or not.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v3pfa805/1/ - Any error in your browser console

Comment: simply change this: <div class="header"><span>Expand</span> to <div class="header"><span>Collapse</span> for its working for meaning of header in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have included jQuery. Your code works perfectly fine after including jQuery:

Working code snippet:

```js
$(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);

    $content = $header.next();

    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {

        $header.text(function () {

            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank u for help. now it working properly. i didnt inlcude the <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> link

Comment: @RenyaK I am glad it helped! :) Please mark this answer as accepted so we can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo

```
  $('.content').hide();
   $(".header").click(function () {

   $header = $(this);

   $content = $header.next();

   $content.slideToggle(500, function () {

    $header.text(function () {

        return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
    });
   });

});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yocgcmrr/)**

Answer (score 0):

I little bit change in your code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header"><span>Collapse</span>

</div>
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        <li>This is just some random content.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
$(".header").click(function () {

$header = $(this);

$content = $header.next();

$content.slideToggle(500, function () {

    $header.text(function () {

        return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
    });
});
```

});

You can check result in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnynz92t/)